# Minimal image measuring software

Tags: software-rec, images, measurement

I'm looking for a software which enables to measure a distance in an image.
Something in the style on Photoshop's ruler and 'guides' system is what I have in mind (but I'd take suggestions in other directions too).
Preferably, it should be as minimal as possible in terms of other functionality.

- OS: Windows 7
- An ability to edit the ruler (unit size/numbering) would be nice, but is not a necessity.
- Freeware is preferable but is not a necessity.

Answer (score 3):

I've used [A Ruler For Windows](http://www.arulerforwindows.com/) before, it worked pretty good for what I used it.

Comment: Slightly useful, but not good enough - Mostly I'd like 'guides' to go over the image while measuring and stay there 'till they are cleared. Thanks anyway